# Instagram oauth api gives { "code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No matching code found." }

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram

I am working on an application that integrates with Instagram API to access the user information. I successfully fetch the Access Token using the authorize url but unable to fetch the userId using access_token url:

i am tried both the endpoints:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=48275564e2c445f6b8e1356djfha3e0c&client_secret=ab2062da9f314e3489dke7ae9cbe6e5d&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code
```

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

with the post body as:

```
client_id=48275564e2c445f6b8e1356djfha3e0c&client_secret=ab2062da9f314e3489dke7ae9cbe6e5d&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code&code=1351860224.4827556.5dc92c4d15ea4a4ea1b0d33eaf0eef19
```

(The data in the request is modified), But i am getting the follwing

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "error_message": "No matching code found."
}
```

I have seen tons of queries and questions but could not find any solution to the problem.

The couple of questions i have is:

```
1) is the field code in the URL is same as access_token, if not how could i get the code field's value.

2) is there any other mechanism(API) to fetch the user details given the username is not known.
```

Please help me as i am completely stuck and running out my deadlines.

Comment: why to downvote..please provide any answer or refer1e70363a5a50d9aolve the problem instead of just running away by downvoting..

Comment: Your requests are looking correct, although I haven't used Instagram API yet. However, I googled your problem and noted, you're not the only one having this problem. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/3ShqSHr_-1Q) I would try to drink some tea and wait, maybe they need some background job to setup things for an app or try to create another one.

Comment: This looks like a good question for Instagram's support team. SO is not really the place to get support when a third-party API is failing.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh You fixed your problem already?

Comment: Please find my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886843/instagram-oauth-api-gives-code-400-error-type-oauthexception-error/41746136#41746136).

Comment: Please check this simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59159954/1576416) if you are following the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me unchecking **Disable implicit OAuth** in instagram developer -> manage clients fixed the issue

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted, it fixed it for me too.

Comment: @Saeven It might be because using this option is less secure compare to check this option as Instagram only will allow authorization requests that use the Server-Side (Explicit) OAuth flow, and not client-side. Read more [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/). I would not down vote it, thought.

Comment: for me i had an extra space on my grant_type value "authorization_code " removing it fixed it for me, ops! please check your variables

Answer (score 3):

I found that using either `form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works fine. The most important is the `code` you get from redirect uri is only used by one request. It means you could request the access token **once** for the `code`. If the you request more than one time with same `code`, you'll get the error like this:

```
{
    code: 400,
    error_type: "OAuthException",
    error_message: "Matching code was not found or was already used."
}
```

Wish you all the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to urlEncode the redirect_uri param to

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
```

And your code param contains the "." character which might be a error.

```
code=1351860224.4827556.5dc92c4d15ea4a4ea1b0d33eaf0eef19
```

might caused the problem

```
"error_message": "No matching code found."
```

"5dc92c4d15ea4a4ea1b0d33eaf0eef19" seems to be the correct code

Comment: Hi Charlie, I tried both the options but no success, Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. It seems that instagram's spam system disable user's access to any non-official application. Just change user's password. In my case it was help.
Also try create another application.

**UPD**

*From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225811/instagram-oauth-returning-no-matching-code-found-at-random-times/30259333#30259333) to another question*

It looks like users get more than one `code`, and you see `first code`, but need `second`. Try `relogin` users, if you gets error. User will not see instagram page with confirm button, just redirections.

Possible algorithm of error:

```
1. User click auth link.
2. Get first code.
3. User click auth link (twice, redirection problem, public auth system, etc.)
4. Get another code (even on the same client_id, redirect_uri).
5. You get first code.
6. But first code already doesn't exists.
```

Comment: This is not true - changing password did not help, creating 2-3 other apps did not help either. Looks like Instagram silently filters out (for some unknown reason) combination user account + IP server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953203/instagram-oauth-returning-no-matching-code-found-on-one-server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here that need redirect url set as http://localhost/signin-instagram

**signin-instagram** part is very important 
So go to Instagram.com/developer ->Manage Client-> Security -> Valid redirect URIs set with that end http:/../**signin-instagram**

Answer (score 0):

Off late instagram python snippet fails due to missing content-type HTTP header

```
response, content = http_object.request(url, method="POST", body=data,headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

adding  application/x-www-form-urlencoded worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I will mention what worked for me.

**Step 1**. Generate a new client secret from you panel.

**Step 2**. Follow the step 1 mentioned [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) to obtain the code again.

**Step 3**. Send the request again with the changed parameters.

Make sure you are logged in the browser when you send the request. You will get the required response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into **Facebook for Developers > Your app**. Click on "Roles" and add an Instagram test-account under **"Instagram Testers"**.
2. Log into instagram.com and go to: [Settings > Security > Apps and Websites](https://about.instagram.com/blog/announcements/increasing-personal-user-data-control), where you will **accept the test invitation**.
3. [Prepare your URL link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions/#step-1--get-authorization), which you will paste into the web browser. Make sure to use a valid redirect URI from **"Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"** from the **Instagram Basic Display** settings.
4. If you did everything right, the Instagram tester account for the app, will have the option to gain access to `user_profile,user_media`. Continue the process to **get the code** which you can [exchange for a short-lived access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions/#step-2--exchange-the-code-for-a-token).