# Instagram oAuth returning "No matching code found" on one server

Tags: oauth, instagram, bad-request

I'm currently receiving

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No matching code found."}
```

while attempting to get a user's access token on one of our servers. This is occurring while using the REST Client Chrome extension and from our web application, on one particular server.

I am able to receive the user's access token from my local machine and a different server using the same code and extension.

Could our IP have been blacklisted from receiving access tokens? Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Heard back from Instagram support, this was an issue on their end and has been fixed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had the same problem last week. Changed server to another IP everything works again. I have no info about why or if our IP got blocked, but it seems so since it works again with a new IP. We follow all Instagram API terms and the only thing I could think of as related was this change last week http://bit.ly/1JClBqG. We asked users to follow us by a checkbox when signing in to the site using relationship scope. But I don't now why we should have been blocked because of that four days after the new terms. Much larger sites are using the same. But we're not using it anymore now.

Comment: I had the same problem,change ip works for me.

Comment: I started getting this error on our Instagram API connection on a development server. I decided to test by creating a bare-bones Instagram OAuth app on that server, but also on another one. The code is identical - only the server IPs are different. It works on one, but not on the other, so I have to conclude that the IP has been blocked on the one that isn't working. I've contacted support but I may as well be shouting down a well - they aren't the most responsive of companies for dev support.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your intuition is correct. It is likely that you made too many incorrect API calls that Instagram disabled your IP. I started dealing with Instagram API this week, at the beginning it was working but today I started getting the same error you got. The code also works fine locally or on any other machine. The only explanation to this is that my IP is blocked. Just switch your IP and you should be fine!

Comment: Switching IP is definitely not so easy. We work in a local environment so we cannot change IPs of all developers within our network. I would recommend trying to hide your IP by using free local proxy, use e.g. tor (https://www.torproject.org/) but you need to initiate also routing for PHP (e.g. https://github.com/Kaiserbald0/PHP-Tor-Proxy/blob/master/proxyConnector.class.php)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**:
The reason for this error is the ip address from which you are trying to connect to Instagram and get access_token. After contacting my network provider and changing my ip everything got fixed.

To figure out if your issue is caused by your local ip (not the server ip) try to connect to your app via mobile network or any other network different from yours:
- If it works you need to change your local ip. 
 -If it does not work - change your server ip cause it is probably banned by instagram for lots of malicious requests.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same trouble: users couldn't authenticate through Instagram and the error returned was "OAuthException" and "No matching code found." Started on 4/28/15 but didn't catch until two days later. Only in production, not staging, so it was almost certainly IP.

I posted to the Instagram developer help center (https://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277) yesterday at 7pm and the problem was fixed by this morning, with a cryptic email from their support at 11am ("The issue has been resolved").