# Can't get access token for Instagram in staging environment

Tags: c#, instagram-api, oauth-2.0

Since yesterday, I have an issue when coupling Instagram accounts with our application. The code works fine locally though, the problem only affects the test / production environments.

First, I retrieve `code` via the call:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&response_type=code&state=[state]&scope=likes+comments+relationships+public_content+basic+follower_list
```

This call makes a callback with the value, which is then used in the following code block:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection
                   {
                       ["grant_type"] = "authorization_code",
                       ["client_id"] = _clientId,
                       ["client_secret"] = _clientSecret,
                       ["redirect_uri"] = callbackUrl,
                       ["code"] = code
                   };
    var response = wb.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", data);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstagramAccessTokenResponse>(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
}
```

This solution worked fine so far, but suddenly I got the following response

> message: {
>       "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used.",
>       "code": 400,
>       "error_type": "OAuthException"
>   }

Any ideas what could be the reason?

**UPDATE**

As a few posts mentioned, after a few days of waiting, the issue solved itself, now it's working again, without changing anything on our side.

Comment: It is possible this issue to be related with Instagram: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886843/instagram-oauth-api-gives-code-400-error-type-oauthexception-error

Comment: @mybirthname sadly I have the same issue with disabled implicit oauth too

Comment: Few months ago there was exactly the same issue. We have the same problem now. Last time we just reported an issue via Instagram and after a day or two, it was magically resolved... We reported the issue again and we're waiting for response or fix. You can report issue too, maybe it will help get it fixed sooner.