# Instagram OAuthException code 400, without specific reason

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

Our app allows users to sign in with Instagram.
Everything works well in general but one user just submitted the issue:

- When he tries to authorize in IG from our app, he receives the following error:

> {"error_type":"OAuthException", "code":400, "error_message":"There was an error with your request. Please try again."}

**Trying again does not help.**
He still sees the issue and cannot connect his IG account.

Can anyone help at least with the direction we have to follow in our investigation?

Comment: We have this exact same issue with a single user. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, specifically with one user.

Comment: Does the user use a proxy or VPN to connect to your app ?

Comment: did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886843/instagram-oauth-api-gives-code-400-error-type-oauthexception-error

Comment: I am experiencing this exact issue, just one particular user.  Wish moderators had not closed this, the only way to reproduce is to use the particular user's credentials which can't be shared on stack overflow.